# Нужно чтобы автоматически выбирался нужный option в select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, калькулятор

Есть select c option. Нужно, чтобы при определённых условиях (зависит от того что я выберу в другом селекте), в нужном селекте, выбирался автоматически нужный option. Использую vue. Сначала думал, может просто присвоить атрибут selected. Но честно говоря сомневаюсь.

Допустим есть:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="11">text11</option>
    <option value="22">text22</option>
    <option value="33">text33</option>
</select>
```

Надо с помощью Vue.JS сделать так, чтобы при выборе `<option value="11">text11</option>`, автоматически сам выбирался, к примеру, `<option value="3">text3</option>`.

Comment: Это немного не то

Comment: Да, похоже и правда немного не то, у вас JS фреймворк на фронтенде, а не просто так. Может быть имеет смысл при выборе какого-то элемента в одном списке реагировать на это методами Vue, и менять состояние в другом списке, тоже средствами Vue? Вы не пробовали так еще?

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался) Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было использовать обработку событий v-on:click=""

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно решить, используя [вычисляемые свойства](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

В примере ниже были созданы два списка: изначальный `list1` и меняющийся в зависимости от выбранного значения `list2`.

Для списка `list2` было добавлено дополнительное поле `idForeign`, которое означает то, при каких значения `id` списка `list1` показывать этот элемент.

Значения `id` выбранных элементов сохраняются в структуре `selected` как 
`list1` и соответственно `list2`.

На основе значения `selected.list1` динамически формируется список `list2Select`, значения которого автоматически подставляются в html.

При изменении `selected.list1` происходит автоматическое формирование нового списка `list2Select`.

Готовые списки отображаются в html с помощью цикла [`v-for`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

Привязка значений `selected.list1` и `selected.list2` производится с помощью директивы [`v-model`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8). При изменении значения списка автоматически изменяется значение соответствующей переменной.

Рабочий пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   list1: [ { id: 1, Title: 'Элемент 1' }, { id: 2, Title: 'Элемент 2' }, { id: 3, Title: 'Элемент 3' },  ],
    list2: [  { id: 1, idForeign: 1, Title: 'Элемент 1.1' }, 
              { id: 2, idForeign: 1, Title: 'Элемент 1.2' }, 
              { id: 3, idForeign: 1, Title: 'Элемент 1.3' }, 
              { id: 4, idForeign: 2, Title: 'Элемент 2.1' }, 
              { id: 5, idForeign: 2, Title: 'Элемент 2.2' }, 
              { id: 6, idForeign: 2, Title: 'Элемент 2.3' }, 
              { id: 7, idForeign: 3, Title: 'Элемент 3.1' }, 
              { id: 8, idForeign: 3, Title: 'Элемент 3.2' }, 
              { id: 9, idForeign: 3, Title: 'Элемент 3.3' },  
            ],
    selected: {
      list1: 3,
      list2: 1,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    list2Select() {
      return this.list2.filter( option => option.idForeign == this.selected.list1 )
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<div id="app" class="container mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Список 1: </label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="selected.list1">
            <option v-for="option in list1" :value="option.id" v-text="option.Title" />
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Список 2: </label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="selected.list2">
            <option v-for="option in list2Select" :value="option.id" v-text="option.Title" />
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Этот же пример на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/eywraw8t/27860/

```
list2Select() {
  return this.list2.filter( option => option.idForeign == this.selected.list1 )
}
```

Для красивого отображения списков использован фреймворк bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

я честно говоря не знаю что такое "vue" но ответ вроде бы знаю -

```js
someEnotherSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
    selectWhichYouNeed.value = valueThatYouNeed
});
```